# Failed to execute './tools/motelist-linux'

Tags: contiki

I am using sky motes in cooja simulator of contiki. I want to use `collect-view`. So I added few sky motes in a simulation and right clicked one of the nodes to start `collect-view`. Then I clicked 'Program-Nodes' button.

I got the following error:

```
Programming failed: java.io.IOException: Failed to execute './tools/motelist-linux'.
```

For sky motes, I noticed the `motelist-linux` file is [here](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/tools/sky). So I updated the [lines](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/tools/collect-view/src/org/contikios/contiki/collect/MoteFinder.java#L56-L57) to

```
public static final String MOTELIST_LINUX = "./tools/sky/motelist-linux";
public static final String MOTELIST_MACOS = "./tools/sky/motelist-macos";
```

I have verified that `motelist-linux` & `motelist-macos` files have necessary permissions. But I got the same error again.

```
Programming failed: java.io.IOException: Failed to execute './tools/sky/motelist-linux'.
```

How do I get rid of the error? or

Is there any other way to use `collect-view`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need sudo permissions for accessing serial port in linux. Please open cooja with sudo and try. it might work. There is another possibility that serial port of the mote might be opened by another application. Make sure that no other application is using serial port of the mote which you are trying to program.

Credits: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/issues/2198